# Why am i getting sqlit error to create table?

Tags: android, sqlite

Any one help me out here?This is my table create  command.

```
private final static String CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
+MOVIE_TABLE_NAME+ " ("
+ _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," + MOVIE_NAME + " 
VARCHAR , "+ COUNTRY_NAME + " VARCHAR , "
+ GENRE + " VARCHAR ,"+ GENRE + " VARCHAR , "+ RELEASE_DATE + " VARCHAR , " + 
QUALITY + " VARCHAR);";
```

Answer (score 1):

Look:  `+ GENRE + " VARCHAR ,"+ GENRE + " VARCHAR`  
you are trying to create the same column `GENRE` twice